# Add display field to people search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-search, refiner

I can't find a clear answer on how to add fields to a people search result. Currently it displays position and department. How do I add additional fields to appear under the person searched?

Comment: 2010 or 2013? In 2010 you modify xslt, in 2013 a display template

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 you create a new Display Template by copying the existing Person_Item template. Then add references to the Managed Properties that you want to display. Add the code inline to create the user interface that you like. Copy the Display Template back to the Search folder in the Master Page Gallery. Next create a Result Type rule that shows your display template. Once you are done testing be sure to Publish your display template and any associated assets.

Here's the full walk through: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/